# Android build flavor sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-productflavors

I'd like to create a demo from my application, so I tried to build another flavor, but if I try to run it, I get this exception:
**attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)**

Original Gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        applicationId 'com.myapp.foo'
        versionCode 518
        versionName '4.3.2'
    }
```

and this is my gradle with the two flavors

```
   defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
productFlavors {
    baz {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.baz'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
    foo {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.foo'
        versionCode 518
        versionName '4.3.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: From [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#readonly_dbmoved)
`The SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED error code is an extended error code for SQLITE_READONLY. The SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED error code indicates that a database cannot be modified because the database file has been moved since it was opened, and so any attempt to modify the database might result in database corruption if the processes crashes because the rollback journal would not be correctly named. `
Try removing all versions of your app and install the demo only and see. Don't know if it would help though

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your flavor specific source segmented correctly so that you only have one SQLiteOpenHelper? Meaning you have one under src/baz/java and one under src/foo/java but not one under src/main/java? Or just a single one under src/main/java?

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml provider section, it should be like the below one.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.zoho.invoice.provider.ZInvoiceProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}"
        android:writePermission="${applicationId}.permission.WRITE_SCHEDULE" />
```

So that the appropriate application id will be replaced while build process.

Also, in your whole project where ever, you use your application id, should be replace with the placeholder.

In your Java file, it can be accessed as

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```